# Ubuntu 20.04 ttyS0 service timeout

Tags: 20.04

In qemu, it's ok to login.But when I try to use ubuntu rootfs in fpga, /dev/ttyS0 will be timeout.By the way, finally the login service is failed.Does the ttyS0 service will cause login service failed?

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS!

[  593.585413] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <hobot>.
[  699.037204] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/gpsd.sock → /run/gpsd.sock; please update the unit file accordingly.
[  699.112901] systemd[1]: Binding to IPv6 address not available since kernel does not support IPv6.
[  706.549827] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[  708.200900] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  708.489113] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[  708.734143] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[  708.952110] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  709.082221] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Dispatch Password …ts to Console Directory Watch.
[  709.205230] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password R…uests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  709.311796] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point being skipped.
[  709.351265] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  709.420379] systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
[  709.476117] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  709.529575] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  709.573451] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
[  709.633579] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  709.687071] systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Set.
[  709.780783] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[  OK  ] Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[  709.990045] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[  710.132600] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[  710.266438] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket.
[  710.409795] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  710.510228] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  710.616757] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[  712.175643] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[  715.847996] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
         Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[  716.675990] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Trace File System being skipped.
[  722.790069] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting Journal Service...
[  723.155893] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel being skipped.
[  723.343577] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[  724.047826] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[  724.461414] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[  724.687463] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
[  729.325753] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
         Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[  730.203318] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[  736.540544] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[  746.672157] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
         Starting Create System Users...
[  762.714644] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[  779.070595] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[  782.789113] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[  *** ] (4 of 6) A start job is running for /dev/ttyS0 (1min 31s / 1min 32s)
[  800.187428] systemd[1]: dev-ttyS0.device: Job dev-ttyS0.device/start timed out.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/ttyS0.
[  801.487978] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[  802.475959] systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttyS0.service: Job serial-getty@ttyS0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[  802.766200] systemd[1]: dev-ttyS0.device: Job dev-ttyS0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
[  810.989177] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[  OK  ] Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[  819.221695] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[  821.782376] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
[ ***  ] (1 of 3) A start job is running for…rnal Service (1min 55s / 3min 25s)
[  824.098551] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in FUSE Control File System being skipped.
[  824.707863] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Configuration File System being skipped.
[  825.035808] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[***   ] (1 of 4) A start job is running for…rnal Service (2min 11s / 3min 25s)
[**    ] (1 of 4) A start job is running for…rnal Service (2min 13s / 3min 25s)
[  843.290510] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
[  843.982300] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
[FAILED] Failed to start Create System Users.
See 'systemctl status systemd-sysusers.service' for details.
[  860.001854] systemd-journald[322]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
[  861.482120] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[  868.460095] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
[  871.500748] systemd[1]: Failed to start Journal Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Journal Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-journald.service' for details.
[  872.614280] systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Flus…Journal to Persistent Storage.
[  873.085379] systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: Job systemd-journal-flush.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[  876.126004] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
[*     ] (2 of 3) A start job is running for…odes in /dev (2min 49s / no limit)
[  OK  ] Stopped Journal Service.
[  887.660593] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting Journal Service...
[  OK  ] Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Name Resolution.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
[  OK  ] Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Name Resolution.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
[  OK  ] Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on GPS (Global P…ioning System) Daemon Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Remove Stale Onli…t4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
         Starting Modify fstab and mount filesystems...
         Starting Hobot log daemon...
         Starting Login Service...
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Name Resolution.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager.
See 'systemctl status NetworkManager.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Login Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
See 'systemctl status systemd-resolved.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start WPA supplicant.
See 'systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service' for details.
[  *** ] (1 of 3) A start job is running for… log daemon (26min 27s / no limit)
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: I have added all related log. Now I can't enter into console, so I can't execute "ls -l /dev/ttyS0". But I have checked the initramfs which is before rootfs has the /dev/ttyS0.